# Is there a Ruby equivalent to Perl -T file operator? (guess if a file is a text file or not)

Tags: ruby, file, text

In Perl, one of the things that I have been depending on, for fast lookup in EDA databases, is the -T operator. I.E. PERL guesses if a file is a text file or not.
The syntax is very simple:

```
if ( -T $filename ) { #do what you need }
```

Is there something equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: the "perl -T" does not seems to 'guess' if a fil is a text file or not, seems to be different. -T is taint mode, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#SECURITY-MECHANISMS-AND-CONCERNS . So what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @tomsoft is correct. From the Perl help: `-T enable tainting checks`

Comment: i think that this -T function is meant, not the runtime parameter: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Comment: `perl -e 'print "yes, this is a text-file" if -T "/etc/passwd";'`

Comment: Yes, that is the -T function, or file operator. I should have defined my question better...

Comment: `grep` determines binary/text by the presence/absense of a \0 in the file. Perhaps you could use that? Or just shell out to `file`?

Comment: In ruby you can taint by just calling `taint` on the object.